# Comparing and highlighting table data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have table with following structure
[image]

Whenever user click on checkbook and click on link "Compare Diff" table column should highlight if the value is different . Users can select two , once user select two out of three (or more than three)  other row will hide and only comparing rows will be shown.

[Here is the link of the code](http://jsbin.com/ufumiv/edit#preview)

Edits:
How I can add class to colgroup > col if any of the value in that column is diffrent?
Or
How can I add class/highlight div of the selected row compared td?

Comment: If you select more than 2 products what constitutes a different value?   Are we checking if they are all the same and if they are not highlight the column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

                $("#compareme").click(function() {
//get all checkboxes that are not selected
                    var not_selected = $("input:not(:checked)");
//get all checkboxes that are selected
                    var selected = $("input:checked");
                    if($(selected).length < 2) {
//you need more than 1 for comparison
                        alert("please select more than 1 product")
                    } else {
//hide the not selected ones
                        $(not_selected).closest("tr").hide();
                    }
//loop through your columns
                    for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                        var prev = null;
                        $.each($(selected), function() {

                            var curr = $(this).closest("tr").find("td").eq(i).text();
//if at least one value is different highlight the column
                            if(curr !== prev && prev !== null) {
                                $("col").eq(i).addClass("highlight");
                            }
                            prev = curr;

                        })
                    }

                })
            });
```

Comment: Nice answer! I prepared a fiddle with your solution - http://jsfiddle.net/4KfeU/ - and took the liberty to improve upon. I've added `$("tr").show();` and `$("col").removeClass("highlight");` for when the length is less than two, and the column highlighting loop went inside the else clause. Feel free to re-use the fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do things like this is include the value of your checkboxes as  IDs for your rows.  You can do this easily with PHP or HTML.  So, for example, if you have a checkbox with one  value, make sure its sibling table cell has the value as its ID:

```
<tr>
   <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="click_me" value="2">
   </td>
   <td id="2">
      2
   </td>
   <td id="5">
      5
   </td>
</tr>
```

When you click on the checkbox, collect the values in an array:

```
$('.click_me').click(function(){
   var thisArray = new Array();
   $(this).parent('td').siblings('td').each(function(){
      thisArray[] = $(this).attr('id');
   });
});
```

We now have an array filled with all of this row's values.  Now we need to find all the other rows' values:

```
var otherArray = new Array();
$('.click_me:selected').not(this).each(function(){
   otherArray[] = $(this).parent().siblings('td').each(function(){
      otherArray[] = $(this).attr('id');
   });
});
```

Now we have two arrays: one with the values of the column you've just selected, the other will all other existing ones which are selected.  Now we need to compare them.  If any values match in the two arrays, we can do something like add a class:

```
for (var i = 0; thisArray[i]; i++) {
   if (jQuery.inArray(thisArray[i],otherArray)) { 
      $(this).parent('tr').addClass('selected');
   }
}
```

If a value exists both in `thisArray` and `otherArray`, the parent  for the input you're clicking on will have a class added.  You can use CSS to change the style for this table row, or even for select table cells in that row.

Comment: Using numbers as ids is a bad idea as ids are not allowed to start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to write your code for you, but here's a rough outline of how I'd handle this.

1. Bind a function to the click event of your link. (When the compare link is clicked, it fires the function).

Then, the function does:

1. Remove all the unchecked rows (probably loop through all the rows, look into it to see if they have an unchecked checkbox, and remove them).
2. Take the first checked row out of the remaining rows, and walk through it's cells. For each cell you compare it's value to the one of the next row. A rough untested script:

   ```
   var c = 1; //start from column 1, because 0 is the Product Name
   $('table tr')[0].each(this.children('td'), function(){
       if(this.val() == $('table td')[1].children('td')[c].val() {
           //apply a style to the current cell here
       }
       c = c + 1;
   });
   ```

Hope this helps you on your way a bit? Please note that I wrote this off the top of my head just to give an indication of the way I'd handle this. Don't copypaste it, probably :P